# Affine transformation matrix for conversion between line and rectangle

Tags: matrix, geometry, transformation, cgaffinetransform, affinetransform

Is there a way using an affine transformation matrix to convert between a rectangle of zero height (i.e. effectively having 2 different end/corner points) and a rectangle of > zero height (i.e. having 4 different end/corner points)?

If not, does another kind of transformation exist that can do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not affine transformation.

In layman terms - you can make zero height rectangle with scale(stretching) matrix with [coefficient k=0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Stretching), but inverse process requires impossible coefficient `1/0`

In some 3D programs such
process is called "extrusion" or "Push/Pull", and to implement it, you need instruments completely different from affine transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, there is no such transformation because a line segment has zero measure while a rectangle has a finite measure. Said differently, an endpoint of the segment cannot map to two corners at a time.

You need to supply more context.